# How to use daterangepicker package with Angular?

Tags: angular, daterangepicker

I was trying to use [daterangepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daterangepicker) in an angular project and getting the following errors. Can someone please help me out how to get it working? Thanks!. Here is the stack blitz link for the same. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1hlx6o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he package you show need jQuery and moment. Personally I think that is not a good idea use jQuery and Angular, but if you want to include see, e.g. [this link](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176T)

```
npm install jquery — save
```

And edit your angular.json adding in scripts

```
      "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        ]
```

And use

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

In your component

NOTE: use ngOnInit, not the constructor

NOTE2: don't forget include the daterangepicker.css in your style

See [your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hrsjz9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample of dateRangePicker based on "ng-bootstrap".

[angular dataRangePicker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skbpc8-38cbew?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: can you please suggest a solution with the same package I have sent?